# nano highlighting fails in matching shell array brackets

Tags: bash, nano, syntax-highlighting

The last two array expansions don't get proper highlighting:

[image]

This is the setting in `sh.nanorc` that defines it:

```
# More complicated variable names; handles braces and replacements and arrays.
color brightred "\$\{[#!]?([-@*#?$!]|[0-9]+|[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*)(\[([[:space:]]*[[:alnum:]_]+[[:space:]]*|@)\])?(([#%/]|:?[-=?+])[^}]*\}|\[|\})"
```

What do I have to fix in the regex to catch this miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regexes like that are a bit of a write-only language, but I think the `(\[([[:space:]]*[[:alnum:]_]+[[:space:]]*|@)\])?` in the middle catches the array indexes. It also doesn't recognize `[*]` as an index.

It's hard to fix that properly, as array indexes can be almost arbitrary shell "expressions". In an integer-indexed array, the index is taken as an arithmetic expansion, and something like `[i+j]` works to use the sum of `i` and `j`. In an associative array, it could be e.g. `[$x$y]` for concatenation. It could also be `[i+a[j]]` if one were to be doing something excessively complex in the shell. Parsing that for syntax highlighting would pretty much require a full parser, not a simple regex. (And then there's command substitutions, but let's not go there...)

Anyway, it's easy to make it accept the `[*]` and one `$` in front of the variable name, here's the changed part:

```
... (\[([[:space:]]*\$?[[:alnum:]_]+[[:space:]]*|[@*])\])? ...
                    ^^^                          ^^^^
```

And the resulting full line:

```
color brightred "\$\{[#!]?([-@*#?$!]|[0-9]+|[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*)(\[([[:space:]]*\$?[[:alnum:]_]+[[:space:]]*|[@*])\])?(([#%/]|:?[-=?+])[^}]*\}|\[|\})"
```

As far as I can see, `${arr[]}` is an error, so I'm not sure if it should be highlighted in full or not.

If that's the regex from the latest version, you might want to consider also posting a bug report.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This does fix the index case.